# bundling express-handlebars application with parcel

Tags: express, parceljs, express-handlebars

I have a website that uses express-handlebars for templating. I now find myself needing to use a bundler for one of the pages that is rendered through express-handlebars. I tried setting up webpack, but it is far too complicated for me. I saw Parcel is "no-config" and have been reading over usage. However, I can find no documentation on how to set up Parcel for use with an express app that uses express-handlebars.
What would be the required directory heirarchy and config for accomplishing this?